# input user string into a looping array

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

When I attempt to put a string into the console, my loop won't add my string into my array but instead goes straight to the error. What am I missing here?

```
public static void main(String[]args)
  {
      System.out.println("Trucks running today (min 2):  ");
      Scanner trucks = new Scanner(System.in);

      int userTrucks = trucks.nextInt();
      int [] x = truckNumberArray(userTrucks);
        if(x == null) 
            {
                System.out.print("Error: must be at least two trucks.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
    Scanner size = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [] largeSmall = new String[x.length];
    for(int t = 1; t<x.length;t++)
         {

            System.out.println("Truck is large or small (large max = 100, small max = 10)?  ");
            largeSmall[t] = size.nextLine();
            if (largeSmall.equals("small")) 
                {  
                    System.out.print(" "); 
                }            
            else if (largeSmall.equals("large")) 
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } 
            else 
                {
                        System.out.println("error");
                        System.exit(0);
                }

         }              
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice this: `if (largeSmall.equals(...`

Modify:      `if (largeSmall[t].equals(...`

Comment: It is my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

You can't access any array element directly by using the name of that array, the position is also to be specified. Like  `String [] largeSmall = new String[x.length];`
This is an String array and has to be accessed as `largeSmall[t].equals("small")`.